# Storing multiple inputs in database in single query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```html
<form method="post" action="formProcessing.php">
  <input type="text" name="uses[]">
  <input type="text" name="uses[]">
  <input type="text" name="uses[]">
</form>
```

I have two database tables one called info other uses. info table contain column name *inf_num*, Is there a way where i can get the last row inf_num and insert the above inputs in uses in one query. For instance if i was to do it manually i would check the last row myself so if it's **10** i would do the below:

```
INSERT INTO uses (id, uses) VALUES (10, 'useZero'), (10, 'useOne'), (10, 'useTwo');
```

How would i go about doing it dynamically with php using the above form:

Comment: iterate over `$_POST['uses']` ? tried that?

Comment: So $_POST['uses'] array behave just like any other array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try To Make A Query Like This

```
<?php

//Your input is array of your input.
$yourInput = array(10,20,26);

$query = "INSERT INTO uses (id, uses) VALUES ";

foreach($yourInput as $value ){
 $query .= "(10, '$value')".",";
}

echo $query;
//Output
INSERT INTO uses (id, uses) VALUES (10, '10'),(10, '20'),(10, '26')
```

Tested **[Here](http://www.writephponline.com/)**
Than Execute this Query

But Remember Youe code is not secure. it is possible to do a sql injection so kindly read **[this note.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** and make it more secure.

Comment: Ever Heard Of SQL Injection?

Comment: @YourCommonSense
Obviously heard.But here as per users insert field name it looks like testing is working so i dont think here is require sql injection.
still updated anwer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create trigger on **uses** table to set last inserted id of **info** table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER uses_before_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `uses` FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN                            
           SET NEW.id = (select id from info order by id desc LIMIT 1);    
      END
```

After, create trigger you can execute insert query directly.

```
INSERT INTO uses (uses) VALUES ('10'),('20'),('26');
```

Comment: which gentleman has voted down, please explain the problem with answer ..

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO user( id, uses )
 SELECT MAX(id), 'userOne' FROM info
 UNION ALL
 SELECT MAX(id), 'userTwo' FROM info;

Answer (score -1):

We can make it possible via query as well.

```
INSERT INTO uses( id, uses ) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(inf_num) from info), 
'useOne', (SELECT MAX(inf_num) from info), 'useTwo', (SELECT MAX(inf_num) from 
info), 'useThree')
```